# Vaadin resource planner

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, resources, vaadin

We have just begun to develop in `Vaadin` and are about to start our first project.

The project aims to create an interactive planning board with resources on the horizontal axis and dates on the vertical axis.

The ability to drag and drop bookings for a particular resource is required.

We have seen this component in `Smart GWT`, and think that it looks promising:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#databound_timeline_new

Does anyone have tips on similar components for `Vaadin`?
Or is it better to build a solution from scratch?

We have made this mockup showing the concept:
[image: Mockup of drag and drop requirement]

Grateful for all sorts of advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be doable with standard Vaadin components and Vaadin drag 'n drop. Take a look at the [DnD](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/drag-drop) samples in Vaadin Sampler.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see gantt diagram add-on: https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-gantt-diagram:vaadin You can see online demo http://vaadin-gantt.bazon.ru/vaadin-gantt-demo/ This add-on is the closest to your needs.

Comment: This component is´t the one we are looking for. I think we need a calendar widget with lots of configuration. Thanks for the tip!